# Where IN clause in LINQ

Tags: linq

My class have a list of another class.

```
 public class CustomerRequest : BaseEntity
 {
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int Code { get; set; }
  public virtual List<TechnicalOfficer> TechnicalOfficers { get; set; }
 }

 public class TechnicalOfficers  : BaseEntity
 {
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int Code { get; set; }
 }
```

I want to select all `CustomerRequest` that `TechnicalOfficers` are contains special id.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to select all `CustomerRequest` that `TechnicalOfficers` are contains special id.

Use `Any` (or perhaps `All`) with `Contains`.

```
var specialIds = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };

var customerRequests = CustomerRequests
    .Where(cr => cr.TechnicalOfficers.Any(to => specialIds.Contains(to.Id)));
```

Comment: Thanks, specialIds is list of TechnicalOfficers?

Comment: No, it's a collection of your special identifiers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I use `_db.CustomerRequests.Where(w => w.TechnicalOfficers.Any(e=>e.Id==user.UserId))`